# Moq - Verify method call that has a params value

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to test with Moq that a method that has a "params" list is called, but for some reason this is failing. The method signature is something like this :

```
void AttachAsModifiedToOrders(IOrder order, params 
       Expression<Func<IOrder, object>>[] modifiedProperties);
```

Then in the Mock setup i've done something like this to do a simple "remove / insert" from the mocked collection :

```
MockEntities.Setup(n => n.AttachAsModifiedToOrders(It.IsAny<DataAccess.Order>()))
    .Callback<IOrder, Expression<Func<IOrder, object>>[]>((order, expr) => 
      { Orders.Remove(Orders.Where(o => o.Id== order.Id).First()); 
      Orders.Add((DataAccess.Order)order); });
```

Finally, the verification :

```
MockEntities.Verify(x => x.AttachAsModifiedToOrders(It.IsAny<Order>(), 
     It.IsAny<Expression<Func<IOrder, object>>>()), Times.Exactly(1));
```

I've checked, and the code executes ok and the method is called (the mocked one), but the verification is failing. am i missing something? or is it just that this "params" call is not supported by Moq?

Comment: Ah, ok. I saw an older bug post about 3 and 3.1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had difficulty replicating this. I think there's a typo in your verify:

```
MockEntities.Verify(x => x.AttachAsModifiedToOrders(It.IsAny<Order>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<IOrder, object>>>()), Times.Exactly(1));
```

Should be:

```
MockEntities.Verify(x => x.AttachAsModifiedToOrders(It.IsAny<Order>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<IOrder, object[]>>>()), Times.Exactly(1));
```

I also wonder if the first It.IsAny should be the interface and not the concrete type?

However, this is a overly-complicated test of some bit of functionality, and the code sample is missing a few pieces, like the DataAccess type or class instance (not sure?), Order, and Orders.

To work around that, I created the IOrder interface and a manipulator object that uses the interface, its a bit nonsensical, but it drives the test:

```
public interface IOrder
{
    void AttachAsModifiedToOrders(IOrder order, params Expression<Func<IOrder, object[]>>[] modifiedProperties);

}

public class Manipulator
{
    public Manipulator(IOrder order)
    {
        Expression<Func<IOrder, object[]>> exp = o => new object[0];
        order.AttachAsModifiedToOrders(order, exp);
    }

    public void DoStuff() { }
}
```

I then created a test fixture to validate the params arg:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tester
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var order = new Mock<IOrder>();
        order.Setup(n => n.AttachAsModifiedToOrders(It.IsAny<IOrder>()));

        var manipulator = new Manipulator(order.Object);
        manipulator.DoStuff();

        order.Verify(x => x.AttachAsModifiedToOrders(It.IsAny<IOrder>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<IOrder, object[]>>>()), Times.Once());
    }
}
```

This works for me, so I don't think the problem is the params value and Moq directly. I do think you'd be well off to take a step back and see if you are really unit testing the class that interacts with the Mock, or trying to verify integrated usages of a couple different types. The params and expression tree is a bit of a smell also.

Comment: just realized that the verification was not being called with the array param, but thanks so much for taking the time to make this test. it's a bit cumbersome to have to specify all of this, but well...

Comment: I think that if it is difficult to test, then it is probably difficult to express, and difficult to understand. Its worth considering a look.